# Alternatives to stringifying the variable name in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, macros

In my code, I have repeatedly this expression:

```
T foo;
do_sth(foo, "foo");
```

I am considering stringifying the variable name, like this:

```
#define VARNAME(Var) (#Var)

void do_sth_new(T foo) { do_sth(foo, VARNAME(foo)); };

T foo;
do_sth_new(foo);
```

Is it good practice? Is there any better alternative in C++11?

Comment: As reflection is still missing in the c++ standard, there is no chance to get it working without ugly macro stuff. So yes, it is current standard solution, but not "good" :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you show it, it doesn't work since `VARNAME(foo)` will always be `"foo"` (as this is the parameter's name). You have to write `do_sth_new` itself as macro:

```
#define do_sth_new(_foo) \
  do { do_sth(_foo, #_foo); } while (false)
```

Only then will this:

```
T bar;
do_sth_new(bar);
```

generate `"bar"`.

And no, there is no alternative to using the preprocessor since this is an operation on the lexical level. You'd need LISP-level modification of the AST in the language to have a better solution, which is unlikely to ever happen.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, no. There is still no solution (not even in C++17) to this problem. There might be something once static reflection will be added to C++. But for the time being you're stuck with the macro.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real way to avoid the macro to do the stringify.

What you can do is dress it in a more c++ object-oriented way, especially if you want to do multiple different methods that take an object and its var name, and if this is a debug feature you might want to disable in production.

So I'm proposing you declare a template class DebugContextWrap, and objects of this type (or const ref) can be passed into the function as a single parameter, instead of having 2 parameters.

The one downside is that where your function code actually wants to access the actual value then you would have to perform an indirection through `operator ->` or `data()` as you do for iterators.

You could then write a macro that generates instances of DebugContextWrap - something like:

```
template class FooType
class DebugContextWrap
{
  FooType& fooVal;
  const char* debugName;
  const char* debug__FILE__val;
  const int   debug__LINE__val;
public:
  DebugContextWrap(FooType& fooVal, 
    const char* debugName, const char* debug__FILE__val, const int debug__LINE__val)
  { ... }
  DebugContextWrap(FooType& fooVal) // implicit when caller doesn't use DEBUG_WRAP
  { ... } 
  FooType* operator ->()const
  { return &foo; }
  FooType& operator *()const
  { return foo; }
  FooType& Data()const
  { return foo; }
  const char* DebugName()const
  { return debugName; }

};

#define DEBUG_WRAP(foo) \
  DebugContextWrap<decltype foo>(foo, #foo, __FILE__, __LINE__)

void do_sth(const DebugContextWrap<FooType>& foo);

do_sth(DEBUG_WRAP(foovar));
```