# Simplifying C++ pattern that includes variable name and function output

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this pattern too many times in my code:

```
class c_outcome {
    public:
        bool success;
        std::string error;
};

c_outcome out;
out = do_sth(a, input, "a");
if (!out.success) { return do_sth2(out.error); };
out = do_sth(b, input, "b");
if (!out.success) { return do_sth2(out.error); };
out = do_sth(c, input, "c");
if (!out.success) { return do_sth2(out.error); };
```

How can I shorten it avoiding repetitions? Basically, I would want to:

- Simplify the pattern `do_sth(a, input, "a")`. Maybe following: [Alternatives to stringifying the variable name in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59660682/alternatives-to-stringifying-the-variable-name-in-c11)
- Integrate in one function: `out = do_sth(a, input, "a"); if (!out.success) { return do_sth2(out.error); };`
- Combine everything in one function like: `do_everything(input, a, b, c)`

I don't know if this is possible/convenient, but it doesn't look right to repeat the pattern continuously.

Comment: A possible simplification (although minor) could be to implement a `operator bool` conversion operator for your `c_outcome` class. Then you could just do `if (!out) { /* handle error... */ }`. Another possible minor simplification would be to have your error-handling function (`do_sth2` in your example) take `c_outcome` as argument instead.

Comment: And if the error cases could be seen as *exceptional* then perhaps use exceptions and `try ... catch` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without resorting to ugly macros you can shorten error handling in beautiful functional style. Take a look:

```
class c_outcome {
public:
    bool success;
    std::string error;

    template<class Fun, class...Args>
    c_outcome then(Fun&& fun, Args&&... args) const {
        if (success) {
            return std::forward<Fun>(fun)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        } else {
            return *this;
        }
    }

    template<class ErrorHandler>
    c_outcome except(ErrorHandler&& fun) const {
        if (!success) {
            std::forward<ErrorHandler>(fun)(error);
        }
        return *this;
    }
};

template<class Fun, class...Args>
c_outcome run(Fun&& fun, Args&&... args) {
    return std::forward<Fun>(fun)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

With code like this you can use it that way:

```
c_outcome do_everything() {
    return run(do_sth, a, input, "a")
        .then(do_sth, b, input, "b")
        .then(do_sth, c, input, "c")
        .except(do_sth2);
}
```

The main advantage of this code is being generic. It will handle nearly every set of types you can imagine.

EDIT:
I upgraded the code, so it now can be used somehow recursively to handle errors

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a good way to implement `do_everything()`, because you need the variable name strings. Instead you need to write each variable separately.

One option is to collect the variable names first.

```
// You can also use a macro to simplify this 
const std::vector<std::pair<std::reference_wrapper<type>, std::string>> lst = {
    {a, "a"}, {b, "b"}, {c, "c"}
};
for (const auto& pair : lst) {
    auto out = do_sth(pair.first, input, pair.second.c_str());
    if (!out.success) { return do_sth2(out.error); };
}
```

Another option is to use a lambda to execute the common parts.

```
auto wrapper = [input](const type& p, const char* str) {
    auto out = do_sth(p, input, str);
    if (!out.success) { return do_sth2(out.error); };
};

#define CALL(p) wrapper(p, #p)

CALL(a);
CALL(b);
CALL(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use boost, there's `BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH`. With your example it should look like this:

```c
#define DO_THING_ONCE(_, input, a) \
    out = do_sth(a, input, BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(a)); \
    if (!out.success) { return do_sth2(out.error); }

#define DO_EVERYTHING(input, ...) \
    c_outcome out; \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(DO_THING_ONCE, input, BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__))
```

Basically, 2nd argument of `BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH` is passed to every iteration, and 3rd argument is a sequence which is iterated over, so you only need to convert variadic args to boost pp sequence and write a suitable macro.